# Array of Colors in Windows8 or wpf?

Tags: wpf, arrays, colors, windows-8

I was trying to import my WP7 proj to Windows 8. I have an array of

```
Color[] g_colors = { Colors.Yellow, Colors.Blue, Colors.Brown, Colors.Cyan,
                    Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Gray, Colors.Green, Colors.LightGray,
                         Colors.Magenta, Colors.Orange,Colors.Purple,Colors.Red,Colors.White };
```

How do I do the same in WPF?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What problems are you having?  In theory, the code should work in a WPF app as you write it above.

Comment: It says Color is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the appropriate namespaces to your code?

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

should sort out the issues.

Following from the comments that you tried this, and it "didn't work", I put together this page in VS.  The .cs file is as below, and all compiles fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class ColorTestPage : Window
    {
        public ColorTestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Color[] g_colors = { Colors.Yellow, Colors.Blue, Colors.Brown, Colors.Cyan,
                             Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Gray, Colors.Green, Colors.LightGray,
                             Colors.Magenta, Colors.Orange,Colors.Purple,Colors.Red,Colors.White };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah Ive tried adding that namespace. Unfortunately it didnt work.

Comment: For the Visual Studio 2012 that I'm using it is Windows.UI; and the rest of the program is same.